# start wih connect by in netezza

Tags: sql, oracle11g, netezza

Imagine the following table

```
DEPARTURE_ID    ARRIVE_ID   ORDER
-------------   ---------   -----
1               3           1
2               3           2
3               (null)      3
10              12          1
11              13          2
12              15          3
13              15          4
14              15          5
15              (null)      6
25              27          1
26              27          2 
27              (null)      3
```

I want to keep the departure_id(s) connected by the prior arrive_id(s)

In oracle11g, I do this

Sample Table

```
create table dep_arrives ( departureid, arrriveid, ord) as
    select  '1',  '3',  1 from dual union all
    select  '2',  '3',  2 from dual union all
    select  '3',  null, 3 from dual union all
    select  '10', '12', 1 from dual union all
    select  '11', '13', 2 from dual union all
    select  '12', '15', 3 from dual union all
    select  '13', '15', 4 from dual union all
    select  '14', '15', 5 from dual union all
    select  '15', null, 6 from dual union all
    select  '25', '27', 1 from dual union all
    select  '26', '27', 2 from dual union all
    select  '27', null, 3 from dual
;
```

Select statement

```
select departureid
from  dep_arrives
start with ord = 1
connect by departureid = prior arrriveid
```

Result

```
DEPARTURE_ID
1
3
10
12
15
25
27
```

I know there is no start with connect by in netezza so I'm looking for a workaround with netezza sql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think Netezza supports recursive CTEs.

Comment: "connect by" hierarchical queries are proprietary Oracle. The SQL Standard includes recursive queries (recursive CTE), and in the database products that support this feature of the Standard, that's how one would translate Oracle "connect by" queries. As Gordon said, Netezza DOES NOT support recursive queries. If you need support for recursive queries, you will very likely need to choose a different database product. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_with_clause.html

Comment: How do you do this with recursive queries in oracle? (not connect by)